# My fixed position doesn't work properly ? How to fix it?

Tags: html, css

Here is my screenshot :

[image]

Header menu and side menu are fixed position. My problem is if i use chrome then scrolling this page, `header menu` and `side menu` is moving a few px to top, but if i use firefox my fixed position is worked properly. Is there a problem with my css or the browser ?

Comment: It might help if you post the relevant CSS and HTML markup.

Comment: have you tried adding css reset? http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your problem as code is not there but such kind of issues are resolved with this CSS in chrome:

```
#header{
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

are you aware of the behavior of `fixed` position elements? An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the viewport, so you need to add other css properties accordingly to get it displayed properly where you want it to be displayed.
update your question with code that would be more helpful in answering your question properly.